# SQL Server 2014 JSON into table

Tags: json, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and aware that out of the box it does not support JSON.

We are receiving data from a 3rd party supplier that will look like the below:

```
{
  "PersonID": "1",
  "MarketingPreference": "Allow",
  "AllowPhone": "No",
  "AllowEmail": "Yes",
  "AllowTxt": "Yes",
  "AllowMob": "Yes"
}
```

However, we may sometimes also receive the below:

```
{
  "PersonID": "2",
  "MarketingPreference": "DoNotAllow"
}
```

I need to insert these values into a table - what is the best way to do this if SQL Server 2014 does not support JSON?

If I convert the JSON to XML it looks like the below:

```
<PersonID>1</PersonID>
<MarketingPreference>Allow</MarketingPreference>
<AllowPhone>No</AllowPhone>
<AllowEmail>Yes</AllowEmail>
<AllowTxt>Yes</AllowTxt>
<AllowMob>Yes</AllowMob>
```

How do I then extract the values from the XML?

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = N'
<PersonID>1</PersonID>
<MarketingPreference>Allow</MarketingPreference>
<AllowPhone>No</AllowPhone>
<AllowEmail>Yes</AllowEmail>
<AllowTxt>Yes</AllowTxt>
<AllowMob>Yes</AllowMob>'
 
SELECT
    Tab.Col.value('@PersonID','int') AS ContactID,
    Tab.Col.value('@MarketingPreference','varchar(20)') AS Pref,
    Tab.Col.value('@AllowPhone','varchar(20)') AS Phone,
    Tab.Col.value('@AllowEmail','varchar(20)') AS Email,
    Tab.Col.value('@AllowTxt','varchar(20)') AS Txt,
    Tab.Col.value('@AllowMob','varchar(20)') AS Mob
FROM   
    @xml.nodes('/root/') Tab(Col)
GO;
```

But now I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Is there an easier way to select the values from JSON?

Comment: `GO` isn't a T-SQL operator; it doesn't require termination. The `;` goes after your T-SQL statements;`...lowMob>';` and  `...Tab(Col);`

Comment: `GO` isn't a SQL statement but a batch separator; it must never be followed by a `;`. Your XML approach would be decent if your XML was valid, but it's not (you need to wrap what you've got inside an actual root element, e.g. `<root>...</root>`). Last but not least, your query syntax is querying for attributes rather than elements (`PersonID[1]`, not `@PersonID`) and `nodes` should use `/root`, not `/root/`. Fix all that and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Consider upgrading to a newer version then you can use functions such as `OPENJSON()` out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `GO` (never mind `GO;` which is not valid), and your XML syntax just seems to have been plucked from your first search result? Try:

```
SELECT PersonID   = x.p.value('(PersonID)[1]', 'int'),
       MarkPref   = x.p.value('(MarketingPreference)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
       AllowPhone = x.p.value('(AllowPhone)[1]','varchar(20)'),
       AllowEmail = x.p.value('(AllowEmail)[1]','varchar(20)'),
       AllowTxt   = x.p.value('(AllowTxt)[1]',  'varchar(20)'),
       AllowMob   = x.p.value('(AllowMob)[1]',  'varchar(20)')
FROM @xml.nodes('.') AS x(p);
```

Output:

| PersonID | MarkPref | AllowPhone | AllowEmail | AllowTxt | AllowMob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Allow | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=828b1037ba74d152ddd8ea87beed1522)